# How to insert function argument in a $$ $$ string in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

So I have a function with an argument for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUCNTION example(arg int)
RETURNS int4
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

   BEGIN
   --function body
   somequery := $q1$ SELECT field*arg FROM randomtable  $q1$
   EXECUTE somequery;
   END

   $$
```

Right now `arg` is just a string, how do I pass real arg from function argument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, you don't need dynamic SQL to begin with, but if you really do, use a parameter placeholder:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUCNTION example(arg int)
  RETURNS int4
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare
  somequery text;
  result int;
BEGIN
   somequery := 'SELECT field*$1 FROM randomtable';

   EXECUTE somequery
     into result
     using arg;

   return result;
END;
$$
```

But without more information about the real problem you are trying to solve, the above can be simplified to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUCNTION example(arg int)
  RETURNS int4
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare
  result int;
BEGIN
   SELECT field * arg 
     into result
   FROM randomtable;

   return result;
END;
$$
```